# References for $|u(x)|\leq C\, \|u\|_{W_{0}^{k,2}(\Omega)}\,\delta^{t} (x)$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I would like to find references for the following result:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with smooth boundary. Then

For any $t>0$, there exist  positive constants $k$ and $C$ such that
$$|u(x)|\leq C\, \|u\|_{W_{0}^{k,2}(\Omega)}\,\delta^{t} (x),\forall x\in\Omega,\forall u\in W_{0}^{k,2}(\Omega).$$

Here $\delta(x)$ is the distance from $x$ to the boundary of $\Omega$, and $W_{0}^{k,2}(\Omega)$ is the standard Sobolev space, which is the closure of $C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $W^{k,2}(\Omega)$.See the notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space).

Do we have a name for this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement follows from some [Sobolev embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#k_%3E_n/p).

First, we consider the case $t=1$.
If $k$ is large enough, then $W_0^k(\Omega)$ embeds into $C^1(\Omega)$.

Then the inequality
$$
|u(x)|=|u(x)-u(y)| \leq \|u\|_{C^1(\Omega)} \|x-y\|
$$
follows for all $y$ in the boundary of $\Omega$ and $u\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$.
Then your claimed inequality follows by taking the infimum with respect to $y$
and using the above embedding, i.e.
$$
|u(x)|\leq \|u\|_{C^1(\Omega)} \delta(x) \leq \|u\|_{W_0^k(\Omega)}\delta(x).
$$
Then you can use the density of $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ in $W_0^k(\Omega)$
to obtain your claim.

The case $0<t<1$ is not a problem because the domain is bounded.

For $t\geq 1$, we can use a similar method.
Instead of $C^1$ we now need to embed into $C^m$ for some $m\geq 1$.
Then we can use similar estimates, but with higher derivatives
(these follow from higher-order Taylor estimates).
Note that the higher derivatives at the boundary are stilly zero
for elements in $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, which can be used in the argumentation.

I am not aware of a name for this result, and I have never seen it in this formulation.

Comment: How about the case $t>1$?

Comment: @Hana: I added a sketch how this might work, without going into too much detail.

Comment: I got the idea now.